# Servlet context and ServletConfig are the interfaces,How web container implements these?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-container

As far as I know `servletContext` & `servletConfig` are two interfaces that are used to pass  initialization parameters to the servlet using the web.xml deployment descriptor

1.`servletContext`

```
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>ServletConfigTest</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.javapapers.ServletConfigTest</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>topic</param-name>
 <param-value>Difference between ServletConfig and ServletContext</param-value>
 </init-param>
 </servlet>
```

2.`servletConfig`

```
 <context-param>
 <param-name>globalVariable</param-name>
 <param-value>javapapers.com</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Here my question is how  web container implements these  interfaces internally?

Comment: Depending on the web container (if its open source or not) you can read the source and find out how its implemented.

Comment: Could you please give  some good source link??

Comment: depends on what container you are using. For e.g. here is the source for tomcats servlet http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.0/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java?av=f

Answer (score 1):

ServletConfig is one per servlet. 
ServletContext is one per web app.

ServletConfig is configuration information for a single Servlet/JSP page.
ServletContext provides context (background information) to the servlet. It gives information about the web application.

Because of this, ServletContext can facilitate setting and getting attributes between servlets and provide generic functionality like access to request dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

Every container handles the implemntation differently

for example:
tomcat gives a reference of ApplicationContext

and jetty gives a reference of 
SContext(org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.SContext)